# My live Django website works fine, but my local repo is broken

Tags: django, python-3.x, git

So I have my website running and am generally happy with it.

I want to do some updates (add commenting to my blog app and also fix the link from main page to blog). However the website pulled from git does not work locally (error messages at bottom of message). I have had this problem since deleting some image files from the local media (these were my dummy images "uploaded" via the admin page)

I have checked using git push from the website and git pull locally (and even with a fresh git clone locally to another folder). The live website on the server is running the latest code (I restarted nginx and gunicorn and even the whole server using sudo reboot).

I tried python manage.py flush to blitz the local database, but I cannot recreate one locally.

I created a new directory on my local machine and did a git clone, made a virtual env and did a pip install of my requirements.

I have run manage.py makemigrations and manage.py migrate

However, checking out another website I also made locally I can see that somehow on my local machine they are both sharing the same (Postgres) database! I can see this as uploading media on one website affects the other (on my local machine). So I am not sure how to untangle this.

So my question is why is this happening? I don't want to start working directly on the live website!

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

ProgrammingError at /admin/jobs/job/

```
column jobs_job.role does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "jobs_job"."id", "jobs_job"."title", "jobs_job"."role...
                                                    ^
```

Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/jobs/job/ Django Version: 2.2.4 Exception Type: ProgrammingError Exception Value:

```
column jobs_job.role does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "jobs_job"."id", "jobs_job"."title", "jobs_job"."role...
                                                    ^
```

Exception Location: /media/dan/Data/Training/Django/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in _execute, line 84 Python Executable: /media/dan/Data/Training/Django/myvenv/bin/python Python Version: 3.6.7 Python Path:

```
['/media/dan/Data/Training/Django/portfolio',
 '/media/dan/Data/Training/Django/myvenv/lib/python36.zip',
 '/media/dan/Data/Training/Django/myvenv/lib/python3.6',
 '/media/dan/Data/Training/Django/myvenv/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6',
 '/media/dan/Data/Training/Django/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
 '/media/dan/Data/Training/Django/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_blog_zinnia-0.20.1.dev0-py3.6.egg']
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have not run migrations

Try,
./manage.py migrate

Comment: I thought this was the problem but actually when I run python manage.py migrate (or ./manage.py migrate) I get: ```Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, blog, contenttypes, jobs, sessions, tools
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply. ``` So my guess is that somehow the database is broken even though it thinks it's migrated?

Comment: I tried deleting all old migration files and then re running makemigrations and migrate but that didn't fix it.

Comment: Make sure you app is in the INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the issue and have posted the problem above.

Answer (score 0):

Silly newb mistake: the postgres database was being shared across two sies on my local machine - so changes to one broke the other. Fixed once linked to a separate database